# How to put a buffer in an HTTP request?

Tags: javascript, http

I’m trying to put a buffer in a request because I have a list of data to import. I want to have success request after one another. The problem I’m encountering is that it waits to upload all data of the request.

Here is the sample data:

```js
[
  {
    "contacts": "dsds@dsd.com",
    "recipient": "dsd@dsd.com",
    "date_sent": "07/08/2020 17:05:04",
    "subject": "repurchase"
  },
  {
    "contacts": "asd@ret.com",
    "recipient": "test@yahoo.com",
    "date_sent": "07/10/2020 17:31:51",
    "subject": "biz"
  },
  {
    "contacts": "we@sdf.com",
    "recipient": "abc@yahoo.com",
    "date_sent": "07/09/2020 13:02:54",
    "subject": "rock"
  }
];
```

```js
const createEngage = async(body) => {
  const BASE_URL = '/api/import'
  var requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: body
    };

  fetch(BASE_URL, requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(async result => {
      console.log(result);
    })
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
}
```

Comment: Hi CoderTrainy and welcome to SO. Could you elaborate what your *buffer* is, what you are trying to do and what exactly does not work. Be as specific as possible.

Comment: Hi Emiel, Im tryng to post 1 data at a time. If 1 data succes, it continues. And one data fail. A pop up will alert. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @trincot!! I'm tryng to get it back. I dunno what happend. Thanks for the help man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably want to do is to *loop* over your data and use `async / await` to wait at each iteration. Your implementation of your asynchronous function currently does not `await` anything. Instead it should `await` the `fetch` request and the decoding of the body with `response.text()`.

Check the response for errors and wrap the `fetch` request in a `try...catch` block. If an error occurs then the `catch` block will be executed. Otherwise check the [`response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object for any states or errors you want to include.

```
const data = [
  {
    "contacts": "dsds@dsd.com",
    "recipient": "dsd@dsd.com",
    "date_sent": "07/08/2020 17:05:04",
    "subject": "repurchase"
  },
  {
    "contacts": "asd@ret.com",
    "recipient": "test@yahoo.com",
    "date_sent": "07/10/2020 17:31:51",
    "subject": "biz"
  },
  {
    "contacts": "we@sdf.com",
    "recipient": "abc@yahoo.com",
    "date_sent": "07/09/2020 13:02:54",
    "subject": "rock"
  }
];
```

```
const BASE_URL = '/api/import'

/**
 * Sends a request for each individual item.
 */
const createEngage = async body => {
  const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body
  };
  try {
    const response = await fetch(BASE_URL, requestOptions);
    if (!response.ok) {
      alert('Your request has failed');
      return null;
    }
    const text = await response.text();
    return text;
  } catch(error) {
    alert('Your request caused an error');
  }
};

/**
 * Loop over each item and call createEngage.
 * Wait for the request to finish and continue.
 */
const createMultipleEngages = async data => {
  for (const item of data) {
    const result = await createEngage(item); // This will make the loop wait every time.
    console.log(result);
  }
};

// Call the function and start looping.
createMultipleEngages(data);
```

Comment: Thanks @Emiel Zuurbier!!

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it answered your question and resolved you issue.